# Number of Binary Operations On a Set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

For a group $[S,*]$ where $S=\{a,b\}$, how come there are $2^4$ binary operations that can be defined on $S$ instead of $2^2$? I can only see $a*a$, $a*b$, $b*a$, and $b*b$, which is $4=2^2$. What other operations can possibly exist? What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition a binary operation on $S$ is a function from $S^2$ to $S$.

You are correct that $S^2$ has cardinality $2^2$, that is to say $a\ast b$, $a\ast a$, $b\ast a$ and $b\ast b$ are the only *inputs* for a binary operation on $S$, but there are $2$ choices for each *output* corresponding to each input, yielding $\underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot\ldots\cdot 2}_{2^2 \mbox{ times}}=2^{(2^2)}$ binary operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^2$ elements in the cartesian product of S i.e. $S^2$ in this case and since every element in the set $S^2$ can be related to either $a$ or $b$, therefore the total number of such binary operations is $2^{2^2}=2^4=16$.